# Move semantics appear to add additional overhead in the simplest possible* example

Tags: c++

* I believe this is the simplest possible example, but if I'm incorrect please let me know.

https://godbolt.org/z/neaTse

I'm attempting to learn and understand move semantics and some of their intricacies, but I've hit a bit of a snag. When attempting to compare the following 2 code snippets, the code using move semantics ends up with 8 additional lines of assembly and 2 additional moves (15 for move, 13 for no-move).

Move:

```
#include <utility>
template<class T> 
void swap(T& a, T& b) 
{ 
  T tmp(std::move(a));
  a = std::move(b); 
  b = std::move(tmp);
} 

int main(){
    int a, b;
    swap(a, b);
}
```

No-Move:

```
template<class T> 
void swap(T& a, T& b) 
{ 
  T tmp(a);
  a = b; 
  b = tmp;
} 

int main(){
    int a, b;
    swap(a, b);
}
```

Move generated assembly:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    void swap<int>(int&, int&)
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
void swap<int>(int&, int&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
        movl    (%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
        movl    (%rax), %edx
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movl    %edx, (%rax)
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
        movl    (%rax), %edx
        movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movl    %edx, (%rax)
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

No-move generated assembly:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    void swap<int>(int&, int&)
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
void swap<int>(int&, int&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movl    (%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movl    (%rax), %edx
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movl    %edx, (%rax)
        movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
        movl    %edx, (%rax)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

I think the the way I've internalized or abstracted move semantics for myself, is that they "enable 'newly available' optimization through the removal of costly temporary copies".

- Have I just internalized this incorrectly?
  -Or-
- Is this just failing because I'm using a primitive type?
  -Or-
- Have I just missed the mark entirely?

Comment: You are building without optimizations enabled, adding `-O2` makes both a single instruction (and identical since `int`s don't have meaningful move semantics)

Comment: Enabling optimisations for both gave no asm at all, as expected. Never try to reason about the performance of non optimised code. https://godbolt.org/z/oxnjK6

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but why would it not generate any assembly? Is my example code just too trivial?

Comment: @Skewjo -- The compiler's optimizer is smart enough to figure out the code will lead to nothing, so no assembly was generated.  Aren't optimizing compiler's great?

Comment: Yes. The optimiser in a modern compiler is _very_ clever, and can see that your code has literally no side effects at all, and so throws all of it away.

Comment: (Incidentally your version of swap seems reasonable, although you may want to consider what would happen if `T` has a throwing move constructor/move assignment operator, and what you'd want to do if that were the case. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept)

Comment: @Skewjo Write a program that actually does something with the "swapped" values that will force the compiler to call the function.

Comment: I've written a program that generates ```a``` and ```b``` at randomly at runtime so that it will create assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/YYnE4P .  The assembly ends up *the exact same*, so the conclusion I'm coming to is that I'll only need to use ```std::move``` if I'm writing a compiler.

Comment: @skewjo try to change T to something more complex, containing an owning pointer, like std::vector, the difference is spectacular.

Comment: @Surt I attempted to create and swap 2 vectors with 100 random elements each, but it looks like the swap is still too trivial and being optimized away: https://godbolt.org/z/rYa5on ... I'm getting well beyond my simple example I was wanting to create to help myself understand ```std::move```s usefulness.

Comment: @Skewjo add an std::cout << vec[7] << std::endl; at the end so they compiler at should be challenged by the swap, if that still doesn't give any code set vec[argc] = argc; in main.

Comment: @Surt you mean like this? https://godbolt.org/z/rbv7eW
I feel like I'm just attempting to break the compiler at this point lol

Comment: @Skewjo TL;DR: Don't try characterize performance or overhead *without an actual piece of code you are working on*. Making synthetic "benchmarks" that have any relationship to performance of complex application code is extremely hard. IOW: You're going about it backwards. Don't try to make problems up. Write the code you actually need, and then evaluate *that*. It's the only way to go without rather deep technical understanding of how C++ compilers interpret the high-level code. Alternatively, evaluate the code's side effects, not machine code (i.e. console output, not .S files!).

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, yeah, I kind of figured I was getting into the area of "pre-mature optimization is the root of all of evil", but I was trying to internalize these 2 functions for interviews, future use, etc... I have a difficult time doing that without concrete examples of their use, which is how I arrived here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem is inlining and effective optimization, to [get around](https://godbolt.org/z/6Mz8P8) it I've annotated it with `__attribute__((noinline))`.

I've made a class to handle the move

```
class mover {
public :
  int *ptr { nullptr };
  __attribute__((noinline)) mover() : ptr(new int(42)) { }
  __attribute__((noinline)) mover(mover & other) {
      delete ptr;
      ptr = new int(*other.ptr);
  }
  __attribute__((noinline)) mover& operator= ( mover && other) {
      delete ptr;
      ptr = other.ptr;
      other.ptr = nullptr;
      return *this;
  } 
  __attribute__((noinline)) mover& operator= ( mover & other) {
      delete ptr;
      ptr = new int(*other.ptr);
      return *this;
  } 
  __attribute__((noinline)) mover(mover && other) {
      ptr = other.ptr;
      other.ptr = nullptr;
  } 
  __attribute__((noinline)) ~mover() {
      delete ptr;
  }
};
```

Specific doesn't use smart pointers to be able to see what goes on.

The move swap now looks like this calling the correct constructors and operators

```
void swap<mover>(mover&, mover&):
        pushq   %r12
        movq    %rdi, %r12
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsi, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, %rsi
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        call    mover::mover(mover&&)
        movq    %rbp, %rsi
        movq    %r12, %rdi
        call    mover::operator=(mover&&) [clone .isra.0]
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
        movq    %rbp, %rdi
        call    mover::operator=(mover&&) [clone .isra.0]
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        call    mover::~mover() [complete object destructor]
        addq    $24, %rsp
        popq    %rbp
        popq    %r12
        ret
```

And the copy swap looks like this calling copy and copy assign.

```
void swap<mover>(mover&, mover&):
        pushq   %r12
        movq    %rdi, %r12
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsi, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, %rsi
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        call    mover::mover(mover&)
        movq    %rbp, %rsi
        movq    %r12, %rdi
        call    mover::operator=(mover&) [clone .isra.0]
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
        movq    %rbp, %rdi
        call    mover::operator=(mover&) [clone .isra.0]
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        call    mover::~mover() [complete object destructor]
        addq    $24, %rsp
        popq    %rbp
        popq    %r12
        ret
```

This biggest effect are the different move constructor

```
mover::mover(mover&&):
        movq    (%rsi), %rax
        movq    $0, (%rsi)
        movq    %rax, (%rdi)
        ret
```

and copy constructor

```
mover::mover(mover&):
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsi, %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movq    $0, (%rdi)
        movl    $4, %edi
        call    operator new(unsigned long) // <---- new
        movq    0(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    %rax, (%rbx)
        movl    (%rdx), %edx
        movl    %edx, (%rax)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

With the `new` call in the latter.